# PHP Database Query - Doesn't Work First Time (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Having a nightmare here and can't work out what's wrong. Basically I have a codeigniter setup that is running a couple of database queries but for some reason it doesn't seem to work the first time after a refresh.

So this is what is currently happening: I submit the form and the form data goes in to the database correctly, however the $property_id ends up blank in createInitialTenancy() function and the $tenancy_id ends up blank in the insertBasicInfo() function.

If I then submit the form again (either by submitting without a refresh or by refreshing) then both these values are populated.

Can anyone explain a reason behind this?

**Controller:**

```
public function new($property_id) {
  // Check for a property ID. Redirect to dashboard if none present.
  if(!$property_id) {
    redirect(base_url());
  }

  // Check for the form having been submitted
  if ($this->input->post()) {

    // Strip form data for XSS
    $form_data =  $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post());

    // Create the initial tenancy entry in the database
    $tenancy_data['property_id'] = $property_id;
    $tenancy_id = $this->tenancy_model->createInitialTenancy($tenancy_data);

    // Empty tenant array. We've dealt with this elsewhere
    unset($form_data['tenant']);

    // Insert the data to the tenancy.basic_info database
    $form_data['lead_tenant_id'] = $_SESSION["tenant_id"];
    $form_data['property_id'] = $property_id;
    $form_data['tenancy_id'] = $tenancy_id;

    $this->tenancy_model->insertBasicInfo($form_data);
  }

  // Security token required for the form
  $csrf = array(
    'name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
    'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
  );

  $this->load->view('header-signin');
  $this->load->view('tenant/tenancy/new', $csrf);
  $this->load->view('footer-signin');
}
```

**Model:**

```
class Tenancy_model extends CI_Model {

  function __construct() {
    $this->load->database();
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function insertBasicInfo($form_data) {
    $this->db->insert('tenancy_basic_info', $form_data);
  }

  public function createInitialTenancy($data) {
    $this->db->insert('tenancy_tenancy', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
  }

  public function getTenancyByPropertyID($property_id) {
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from('tenancy_tenancy');
    $this->db->where('property_id', $property_id);
    $tenancy = $this->db->get()->result();
    return $tenancy;
  }
}
```

**tenancy_tenancy Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `tenancy_tenancy` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `property_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=59 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**tenancy_basic_info Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `tenancy_basic_info` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tenancy_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lead_tenant_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `property_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `more-tenants` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pets` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pets_info` text,
  `cars` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `number_of_cars` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `information` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=43 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: May or may not be the problem but `new` is a PHP keyword and so should not be used as the name of a function. [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php)

Comment: @DFriend Didn't fix it :(

Comment: Too many questions to ask regarding what you are trying to achieve here... so for starters I'll suggest that you first look into Codeigniters Forms and Form validation in the user guide. ie you are not performing any validation.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I think I just discovered it's a Sequel Pro issue. I think the data is actually there just not displaying for some reason!

Comment: So is this method the action of your form?

Comment: Might be useful to see the code for 'tenant/tenancy/new'  (which I trust you have renamed by now:) )

Comment: So do you have some other method that is the action for the form, and then you call this "new" method ( badly named as noted by @DFriend )? So you are passing in a parameter of property_id and using post and session vars? Seems that there is too much going on here...